# Unable to create private key for Firebase Admin SDK - Failed to generate a private key. Please try again in a few minutes

Tags: firebase, firebase-admin, private-key

When I try to generate a new private key to use the Firebase Admin SDK I get the error:

> Failed to generate a private key. Please try again in a few minutes.

The error persists now for a while already. I never created a private key for this project so far.

My service account has the following roles (translated to english):

```
Cloud Functions Admin
Service account token creator
Firebase Admin SDK administrator service agent
Firebase Authentication Administrator
```

Anyone any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I found out why I got this error or at least how to fix it:

I added `Storage Admin` as a role to my service account and I was able to generate a new key.